# Selenium webdriver not working with DOM elements in firefox 24.0

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

Webdriver unable to find elements in firefox 24.0.
The webdriver got stuck after maximizing the window and opening the url.
Trying to find webelement but webdriver does nothing and not giving any error/exception on the console
The same code working on Chrome and with lower version of firefox

Comment: Can you please add the code that is not properly working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the incompatible Selenium version - most recent is 2.35 which is probably running only on FF 23. So you have to stick to the FF 23 until the new version of Selenium is released.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any updates when the next release for Selenium webdriver is expected

Comment: You are welcome. It's also a good habit to accept or upvote helpful answers here on SO (so you know that for future reference).

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue with the current version of selenium and had to downgrade all the way down to firefox v19 to gain stability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to risk some instability you can grab a dev snapshot that may already have the fix you need.  The snapshots are at http://ci.seleniumhq.org/